# bit change location in bit stream

Tags: php, arrays, bit

bit stream:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

desired outbpu:

```
4-7,10-11,15
```

my function:

```
$flag = 0;
$str = '';  
for( $i=0; $i < count( $array ); $i++ ){
    if( 0 == $array[$i] ){
        $flag = 0;
        continue;
    }
    if( $i > 0 && $session_array[$i] == $session_array[$i-1] ){
        $flag = 1;
        continue;
    }
    $str .= (string)$i+$flag . ',';
}
```

But it does not produce the desired output. any suggestions?

Comment: I'm on it - almost done.

Comment: How do you get these 5 numbers out of these 16 digits?

Comment: @Rizier123 `4-7`, `10-11` and `15` are the ranges of positions where the "bit 1"s are.

Comment: Well yeah - It's made some issues displaying - Deleted my post - Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variant with array_reduce

```
$s = '0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0';

$array = explode(' ', $s);

$output = '';
// to make count from 1 but 0
array_unshift($array, 0);
// keys with value 1
$keys = array_keys($array, 1);
$c = array_reduce ($keys, function($c, $item) use (&$output) {
    if ($c[0] == -1) return array($item, $item); 
    if($item == $c[1]+1) return array($c[0], $item); 
    $output .= ($c[0] == $c[1] ? $c[0] : implode('-', $c)).','; 
    return array($item,$item);
}, array(-1,-1));

$output .= ($c[0] == $c[1] ? $c[0] : implode('-', $c));
echo $output;
```

result `4-7,10-11,15`